# Validation of a specific div using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two main divs, one for login other for sign up.
I want to validate signup div only when user click for sign up button, when user click for login button the signup validation should not be executed.
here is my html code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

            <%--Login div--%>
            <div class="navbar-form navbar-right col-md-9">
                <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobleNoLogin" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPssword" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogIn" runat="server" Text="Login" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnLogIn_Click" Style="margin-top: 9px;" /><br />
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="rememberCheckBox" Text="Remember Me" runat="server" ForeColor="White" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;
            </div>


            <%--Singup div--%>
            <div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                        <!-- Div Panel -->
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">

                            <!-- Panel Heading -->
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="panel-title" style="text-align: center"></div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End panel heading -->
                            <!-- Panel body -->


                            <!-- Sing Up -->
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <!-- FullName -->
                                <div class="input-group input-lastname" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" placeholder="Full Name" runat="server" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Email -->
                                <div class="input-group input-email">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i></span>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email id" runat="server" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Password -->
                                <div class="input-group input-password" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" runat="server" autocomplete="off" TextMode="Password" class="form-control" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <!-- ConfirmPassword -->
                                <div class="input-group input-con-password">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtConformPassword" placeholder="conform Password" runat="server" autocomplete="off" TextMode="Password" class="form-control" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Company-->
                                <div class="input-group input-dropdown" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCompany" DataTextField="company" DataValueField="company_id" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Company</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Categoery-->
                                <div class="input-group input-dropdown" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategoery" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCategoery" DataTextField="CategoryTitle" DataValueField="CategoryTitle" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Category</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Mobile-->
                                <div class="input-group input-lastname" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNo" placeholder="Mobile" runat="server" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Submit-->
                                <div class="form-group login-button">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnSingUp" runat="server" Text="Submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3" Style="margin-top: 20px" OnClick="btnSingUp_Click" />
                                        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-top: 20px">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Sing Up -->
                            <div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ENd form -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End panel group -->

            </div>
            <!-- End col div -->
        </form>
```

Comment: just give login and signup their own `<form></form>` rather then both have same `<form></form>`

Comment: i am using aspx form that could have a single <form></form> tag..